# How do I verify that TRIM is activated? (Linux)

Tags: linux, ssd, trim

I have kernel*.32 and I use ext4 on my drive. Now I just don't know how to check if trim support is enabled?

Found this: 
http://blog.patshead.com/blog/2009/12/a-quick-and-dirty-wipersh-fix-for-intel-x25-m.html

Comment: I recently also asked this question, and got a great answer from Janne Pikkarainen. http://superuser.com/questions/181238/how-do-i-determine-whether-my-ssd-samsung-um41-supports-the-trim-command/181324#181324

Comment: and this blog post really verifies:
http://andyduffell.com/techblog/?p=852

Answer (score 7):

The TRIM command has only been supported on Ext4 [since kernel version 2.6.33](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Trimming-DRBD-Block-Layer-Virtualisation-and-Tracing-933417.html). It is [disabled by default](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=5328e635315734d42080de9a5a1ee87bf4cae0a4) (as it is slightly experimental), but can be enabled with the `mount` option `"discard"`.

Answer (score 5):

When calling 'mount' on the CLI you should get a response that looks similar to:

```
/dev/sdx on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,discard,errors=remount-ro,commit=0)
```

Note the **discard** option is present, which signifies the volume is mounted with the TRIM option.