# Why don't I have TRIM on Ubuntu 10.04 + ext4 + Samsung SSD UM41 + Latitude 13?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, ssd, ext4, trim

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 and `lshw` shows a "SAMSUNG SSD UM41".  Thanks to SU, I [determined previously](https://superuser.com/questions/181238/how-do-i-determine-whether-my-ssd-samsung-um41-supports-the-trim-command/181324#181324) that my system isn't using TRIM.

Summary:

- my BIOS SATA settings should say AHCI (check)
- kernel .28+ supports it (using .32)
- ext4 supports it (using ext4)
- my disk manfuacturer says I support it
- `hdparm -I /dev/sda` should say that I'm using TRIM (fail! using hdparm 9.30)

How do I determine what's preventing TRIM from being used, and how might I remedy this?

Comment: Does `hdparm -I` explicitly say you're not using TRIM, or does it not mention it at all?  The reason I ask is I believe you need a relatively recent version of hdparm.

Comment: It doesn't mention it at all, but I *was* using 9.30 which I believe should be recent-enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kernel .28 may have included experimental support, but only from **2.6.33** on it is part of the mainstream kernel.  So update your kernel ... or maybe you can activate the experimental stuff somehow (don't ask me).

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this procedure](https://sites.google.com/site/lightrush/random-1/howtoinstalllinuxkernel2635onubuntu1004lucidfromubuntu1010mavericktheeasyway) with 2.6.35-32-generic and Ubuntu 10.04.

> There exist various reasons why we might want to install the newer 2.6.35 kernel that ships with Ubuntu 10.10 on Ubuntu 10.04. Some would want TRIM support, others would want enhanced power saving. Whatever the case the Ubuntu Team has provided an easy way to accomplish this task:
> All we need to do is launch a Terminal and type in:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-backport-maverick linux-headers-generic-lts-backport-maverick
> ```
>
> Reboot the computer. Now we should be running Linux kernel 2.6.35.